# How to locate box2 body?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I add `cocos2d` sprite into body definition `userData` of box2 body.

```
b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
spriteBodyDef.position.Set(...);
spriteBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)sprite;
b2Body *spriteBody = _world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
```

Each sprite has tag. There are number of sprites. I'm not sure how to find body having only sprite tag. I can find sprite itself by using `getChildByTag`, but then how to locate body? Iterate through all bodies and compare userData with sprite found or there is a better way? Feels not natural to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subclassed CCSprite as PhysicsSprite and added b2Body* body as a property.
This way I can directly access the body and call GetPosition().

**EDIT**: I added it as a member(not a property) and wrote a getter for it.

```
@interface PhysicsBall:CCSprite{
    b2Body* ballBody;
}
-(b2Body*)getPhysicsBody;
```

where

```
-(b2Body*)getPhysicsBody{
    return ballBody;
}
```

Comment: How you declared b2Body property in header of subclass?

Comment: have edited my answer..i did not add it as property but as a member ..forgot about that..